# Apache Shiro ThreadContext#bind(Subject) vs ThreadContext.bind(SecurityManager)

Tags: java, shiro

I am just learning Apache Shiro and facing a problem. In examples I see in internet the entry point of thread security is the following code:

```
  try {
        ThreadContext.bind(subject);
        //main code here
    } finally {
        ThreadContext.unbindSubject();
    }
```

However, according to [documentation](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.5.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/util/ThreadContext.html) there are the following methods:

> static void   bind(SecurityManager securityManager) Convenience method
>   that simplifies binding the application's SecurityManager instance to
>   the ThreadContext.
>
> static void   bind(Subject subject) Convenience method that simplifies
>   binding a Subject to the ThreadContext.
>
> static SecurityManager    unbindSecurityManager() Convenience method
>   that simplifies removal of the application's SecurityManager instance
>   from the thread.
>
> static Subject    unbindSubject() Convenience method that simplifies
>   removal of a thread-local Subject from the thread.

Could anyone explain, when (in what situations) we need to bind Subject and when SecurityManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your code is doing, most of the time you just need the reference to your Subject, but, if your custom code does something with a SecurityManager, Shiro provides a utility for that too.

That said, you probably want to use `subject.excute(...)` instead for most cases:
https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#thread-association

TL;DR, unless you have code that uses the security manager directly, use the Thread association automatically via `subject.execute`